# SharePoint online search filters

Tags: search, filter, sharepoint-online

In the search in SharePoint online modern experience I would like to add some filters to the people tab similar to how there are filters on the Files tab.

[image: SharePoint Files tab search with filters]

My People tab looks like this.

[image: People serach tab]

How can I modify the People search tab to add filters? For example I would like to add a Company filter with a list of companies.

Answer (score 0):

Per my knowledge, there is no option to customize SharePoint modern search.

Modifying the People search tab to add filters is not available.